# Дана строка.Если она представляет собой запись целого числа, то вывести 1; если вещественного то 2

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Дана строка.Если она представляет собой запись целого числа, то вывести 1; если вещественного (с дробной частью), то вывести 2; если строку нельзя преобразовать в число, то вывести 0.Вот наработки, но ответ в результате не верный.Помогите исправить

```
str="12.5";
otv=0;
tmp=0;
er=true;
for (i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    switch (str[i]) {
    case '1':
    case '9':otv=1;
    case '.':tmp++;
       default:er=false; 
    }
     }
if(tmp>1){er=false;}
    otvet=otv+tmp;

if(er){console.log('Ответ :'+otv)}
else {  console.log('Ответ : 0')}
```

Решить алгоритмически

Comment: Как вы думаете, в какой case заходит код, если видит цифру 2?

Comment: А [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) / [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) чем не устраивает?

Comment: @ VladD там жеш написано что дана строка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var numberTester = function(text) {
    if (isNaN(text)) return 0;
    var d = parseFloat(text);
    return (d%1==0) ? 1 : 2;
}
```

еще вариант:

```
var numberTester = function(text) {
    var result = 1;
    for (var i in text) {    
        var ch = text[i];
        if ('-' == ch && 0 == i) 
            continue;
        if ('.' == ch) {
            if (result == 2) {
                result = 0;
                break;
            }
            result = 2;
        }
        else if (ch < '0' || '9' < ch) {
            result = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Проверка:

```
var testArr = ["37.5", "37", "ab12", "1.1.1", "-4.5", "4-.5"];
var text = "";
for (var i in testArr) {
    text += testArr[i] + "\t-> " + numberTester(testArr[i]) + "\n"; 
}
alert(text);
```

Comment: но там жестока:(

Comment: Добавил второй вариант

Comment: Неверно: `12ab`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function conv(x) {
  return x.length && x==+x ? 1 + (x%1!=0) : 0;
}
```

Проверка:

```
["", "12", "-1", "0", "12.9", "-1.9", "ui", "8k", "8,9", "12345678901234567890"].map(conv) == "0,1,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,1"
// true
```